# Uploading image with React-Native expo image picker to ExpressJS Using multer gives 500 HTTP ERROR Code sometimes

Tags: mongodb, react-native, express, expo, multer

I'm currently doing a react-native project that i can upload image with Expo-Image picker,axois to ExpressJS and multer, mongoose (Mongodb)

Sometimes it works after couple of tries, but in some device it completely does not work and gives 500 HTTP Error code.

i tried switching from axios to fetch but it still doesnt work

Here's my code

React native:

```
const pickImage = async () => {

        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 0.5,
        });
        if (!result.canceled) {
            setImage({ uri: result.assets[0].uri, type: 'image/png', name: 'uploadingimg' + Date.now() });
        }
    };
```

....

```
 const fetchaddImage= async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("image", image);
            formData.append("username", username)
            const response = await axios.post(apiheader + '/uri',
                formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            });
            const result = await response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            ToastAndroid.showWithGravityAndOffset('Some error has occured, please try again ', ToastAndroid.LONG, ToastAndroid.BOTTOM, 25, 50)
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
            setImage(null)
        }
```

Backend:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
        cb(null, '-' + uniqueSuffix)
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: 1024 * 1024 * 5 });

...

router.post('/uri', upload.single('image'), async function (req, res, next) {

    if (req.file) {
        filename = "/../uploads/" + req.file.filename
    } else {
        filename = "/../assets/default-image"
        //if user didnt upload any image

    }
    try {
        const newuser= await UserModel.create({
            username: req.body.username,
            image: { 
                data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + filename)),
                contentType: 'image/png'
            },

        })

        newuser.save();
        res.send({ "status": "added succesfully" })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
        console.log(error)
    }
```